# Why am i getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) when i try to print a struct using recursion?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I am new to C. I am trying to make a linked list with the following structure.

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};
```

So i am using recursion to create the linked list from a given array.

```
struct ListNode makeNode(int val, struct ListNode* l){
    struct ListNode node;
    node.val = val;
    node.next = l;
    return node;
}

struct ListNode makeNodeFromList(int arr[], int length, int index){

    // Checks if the given index is the last element of the array
    // (Base Condition)
    if ((length-1) == index){
        return makeNode(arr[index], NULL);
    }

    struct ListNode next;
    next = makeNodeFromList(arr, length, index+1);
    return makeNode(arr[index],&next);

}
```

But when i try to print the result using the following code it keeps printing the second element and i get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

```
void printNode(struct ListNode *l){
    // Prints the each value of the struct, separated by tab.
    

    if ((l->next) != NULL){
        printf("%d\t",(l->val));
        printNode((l->next));
    }
    else{
        printf("%d\n",(l->val));
    }
}

int main() { 
    int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
    struct ListNode item;
    item = makeNodeFromList(arr,3,0);
    printNode(&item);
    }
```

*-Edit

The whole code instead of snippets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct ListNode makeNode(int val, struct ListNode* l){
    struct ListNode node;
    node.val = val;
    node.next = l;
    return node;
}

struct ListNode makeNodeFromList(int arr[], int length, int index){
    printf("%d\t", arr[index]);

    // Checks if the given index is the last element of the array.
    if ((length-1) == index){
        return makeNode(arr[index], NULL);
    }

    struct ListNode next;
    next = makeNodeFromList(arr, length, index+1);
    return makeNode(arr[index],&next);

}

void printNode(struct ListNode *l){
    // Prints the each value of the struct, separated by tab.
    

    if ((l->next) != NULL){
        printf("%d\t",(l->val));
        printNode((l->next));
    }
    else{
        printf("%d\n",(l->val));
    }
}

int main() { 
    int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
    struct ListNode item;
    item = makeNodeFromList(arr,3,0);
    printNode(&item);

    }
```

I cant figure out the mistake i made.

I tried to find similar problems but couldn't find a similar case.

Comment: Give us a program instead of a bunch of snippets.  For instance the above is missing headers.

Comment: In the `makeNodeFromList` function you have the *local* variable `next`. The life-time of that variable *ends* when the function returns. Any pointer you save to it will become immediately invalid.

Comment: You need to also learn how to debug seg faults using `gdb` and `core` file. Please refer https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/04/28/debugging-a-segfault-on-linux/

Comment: Not to mention that you only have *one* `next` variable, so all pointer will be pointing to that single variable. Until the function returns, that is. You need to learn about *dynamic allocation* using `malloc` to solve your list problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running you program under gdb, I find that your program segfaults in `printf("%d\t",(l->val));`.  The variable `l->next` cannot be accessed.  As @Someprogrammerdude told you above that it is because it's a local variable `next` in `makeNodeFromList()` is out of scope when it returns.

The minimal fix is (and you need a matching free):

```
#include <string.h>

struct ListNode makeNodeFromList(int arr[], int length, int index){
    if ((length-1) == index) {
        return makeNode(arr[index], NULL);
    }
    struct ListNode next = makeNodeFromList(arr, length, index+1);
    struct ListNode *p = malloc(sizeof(next));
    memcpy(p, &next, sizeof(next));
    return makeNode(arr[index], p);
}
```

Also, your `printNode()` doesn't look right to me.  Try this instead:

```
void printNode(struct ListNode *l) {
    if(!l) return;
    printf("%d\t", l->val);
    printNode(l->next);
}
```

Here is a streamlined version of `makeNodeFromList()`:

```
void makeNodeFromList(int length, int arr[length], struct ListNode nodes[length]){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        nodes[i].val = arr[i];
        nodes[i].next = i + 1 < length ? &nodes[i + 1] : NULL;
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    struct ListNode nodes[sizeof arr / sizeof *arr];
    makeNodeFromList(sizeof arr / sizeof *arr, arr, nodes);
    printNode(nodes);
}
```

Comment: It will be even better if you can explain how you figured out this.. to teach and explain people to do things and try on their own first

Comment: @GauravPathak What do you specially suggest?

Comment: Your debugging approach

Comment: @GauravPathak Happy to update the answer but as far as I am concerned, I did share the process that I used already.

Comment: @GauravPathak  I came to the same conclusion in about 30 seconds of looking at the code. The first red flag is the use of a node constructing function which returns the node structure by value. I immediately wondered: will the caller dynamically (or statically) allocate a node, as required, and then assign the returned value to it? I quickly found the code and the answer is no: the caller just defines a non-static local variable, and assigns the returned node to that. Then returns the address of the local variable, which is a fundamental programming error in C, particularly among beginners.